# What's wrong with this regex pattern?

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I'm trying out one simple regex pattern. But it's behaving strange.

```
re.findall('ABC\-\d{2}\-\d{3,5}(\[[A-Z]\])?', 'ABC-01-1234[Z],ABC-12-5678')
```

The output is always:

```
['[Z]']
```

whereas I want both the strings i.e. `ABC-01-1234[Z],ABC-12-5678` as my matched pattern. `[Z]` is optional. Don't know why `?` is not working correctly.

Comment: Your only group is around `\[[A-Z]\]`?.

Comment: `'(ABC\-\d{2}\-\d{3,5}(?:\[[A-Z]\])?)'`

Comment: @null Thanks. This solved my problem. But syntax wise if I see, my pattern doesn't seem incorrect either !!!

Comment: You need a capturing group otherwise you will match but not grep. `re.findall('ABC', 'ABC,ABC,ABC'); # gives nothing`. while: `re.findall('(ABC)', 'ABC,ABC,ABC'); # gives ['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC']` or `re.findall('A(B)C', 'ABC') # ['B']`

Comment: re.findall('ABC', 'ABC,ABC,ABC') correctly gives me ['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC']

Comment: what about: `re.findall('A(B)C', 'ABC,ABC,ABC')` it gives you `['B', 'B', 'B']`? It seems like you will get a capturing group around your statement if none is provided. In your case you added one for the `[Z]` match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your regex to:

```
re.findall('(ABC\-\d{2}\-\d{3,5}(?:\[[A-Z]\])?)', 'ABC-01-1234[Z],ABC-12-5678')
```

Group around the whole match `(...)`. And non capturing group around your maybe match `(?:...)`

Tested in JS (not sure if will work in Python):

```
'ABC-01-1234[Z],ABC-12-5678'.match(/(ABC\-\d{2}\-\d{3,5}(?:\[[A-Z]\])?)/g); // ["ABC-01-1234[Z]", "ABC-12-5678"]
```

Comment: It's working in python.cheers. But I'm using the pattern with 'findall'